# Converting Java wildcard type argument to kotlin

Tags: java, list, kotlin, wildcard

Trying to learn Kotlin and on one of my classes in Java I have a value that is a list that contains any class that extends a certain interface as seen below.

`List<? extends foo>`

I have previously tried the `out` modifier example:

```
interface foo 
{
   val bar: out List
}
```

and passing the class through the modifier example:

```
interface foo<T> 
{ 
   val bar: List<T> 
}
```

The result wanted is that if two classes extended this interface they could both have this value but one could have a list of type A and one of list type B

Comment: This is not what you need?  `class a : foo<String> {
    override val bar: List<String>
        get() = listOf()
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kotlin equivalent to Java `List<? extends foo>` doesn't depend on what `foo` looks like and doesn't require changing it. It's `MutableList<out foo>` (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections).